# MUI 5 Tab Label Custom Thickness

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to change the thickness of label inside a tab using MUI 5.

Here are what I tried:

```
interface TabPanelProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    index: number;
    value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
        >
            {value === index && (
                <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
                    <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
    return {
        id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
        'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
}

export default function UsersGroupsManagement() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

const StyledTab = styled(Tab)<TabProps>(({theme}) => ({
    '& .MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root': {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
}));

const styledLabel = styled('label')({
    color: 'darkslategray',
    backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
});

return (
    <Box sx={styles.userAccounts}>
        <Box sx={styles.tabbox}>
            <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="User Management Tabs" >
                <Tab label="ADD NEW USER" {...a11yProps(0)} sx={{
                    '& .MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root': {
                        color: 'black',
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                }}/>
                <Tab label="MANAGE USERS" {...a11yProps(1)} sx={{
                    '& .MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root': {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                }}/>
            </Tabs>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                <AddNewUser />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                Item Two
            </TabPanel>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

I tried to create a StyledTab but didnt work.
I tried to create a styled label didnt work at all.
I tried to give css from sx props using  but didnt work.

Can you please explain me how can I manage to make thicker labeled tabs in Material UI v5?

Answer (score 1):

u can follow something like this..

```
    <Tabs
      sx={{
        "& .MuiTabs-indicator": { backgroundColor: "#E86826" },
        "& .MuiTab-root.Mui-selected": { color: "#E86826", fontWeight:"700" },
      }}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="nav tabs example"
      centered
    >
```

Just Edit the tabs and u work is done...hope it helps